# Python create_task does not work in running event loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, event-loop

I have a simple piece of code driving me crazy for a while. I have posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350166/python-event-loop-does-not-work-properly-with-stdin) question some days ago asking `create_task` is not working with `input`. Now I have figured out something related to this. I am running event loop in a separate thread and pushing tasks in it. Very straight forward code.

```
import asyncio
import threading


async def printer(message):
    print(f'[printer] {message}')


def loop_runner(loop):
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop_runner, args=(event_loop,))
    t.start()

    for m in ['hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']:
        print(f'[loop running ?] {event_loop.is_running()}')
        event_loop.create_task(printer(m))
```

Nothing gets printed but these log messages.

```
[loop running ?] True
[loop running ?] True
[loop running ?] True
[loop running ?] True
```

Now if I block in event loop thread and let it run after a pause like this.

```
def loop_runner(loop):
    time.sleep(1 / 1000)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Everything works and this gets printed

```
[loop running ?] False
[loop running ?] False
[loop running ?] False
[loop running ?] False
[printer] hello
[printer] world
[printer] foo
[printer] bar
```

From surface it looks like tasks created in running event loop do not get executed. But why is that?

I have not seen anything regarding this in documentation. In most of the examples I have seen on internet people are creating tasks in loop from other coroutines and awaiting for them. But I think it is legal to use create tasks outside coroutine if you do not want to await for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asyncio How do you use run\_forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642267/asyncio-how-do-you-use-run-forever)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When creating task from outside the event loop thread, you need to use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe). That function will schedule the coroutine in a thread-safe manner and notify the event loop that there is new work to be done. It will also return a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object which you can use to block the current thread until the result is available.

> From surface it looks like tasks created in running event loop do not get executed. But why is that?

Calling [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) is insufficient because it doesn't contain code to "wake up" the event loop. This is a feature - such wakeup is normally not needed, and adding it would just slow down the regular single-threaded use. When `create_task` is invoked from the event loop thread, it is inside an event loop callback, so the event loop can check its task queue as soon as it regains control, when it is done executing the callback. But when `create_task` is invoked from a different thread, the event loop is asleep waiting for IO, so `run_coroutine_threadsafe` is needed to wake it up.

To test this, you can create a "heartbeat" coroutine, which only contains an infinite loop that prints something and awaits `asyncio.sleep(1)`. You'll see that the tasks created with `create_task` get executed along with the heartbeat, which also happens to wake up the event loop. In busy asyncio applications this effect can give the impression that `create_task` from another thread "works". However, this should never be relied on, as `create_task` fails to implement proper locking and could corrupt the event loop internals.

> I have not seen anything regarding this in documentation.

Take a look at the [concurrency and multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading) section.

Comment: Actually I have  already tried `run_coroutine_threadsafe` and I knew it works. I was just curious why `create_task`  does not work. Thanks for linking appropriate part of documentation :) it says *An event loop runs in a thread (typically the main thread) and executes all callbacks and Tasks in **its thread** *. Does that mean it will ONLY execute tasks from the thread it is running in?

Comment: Thanks for adding more details to answer. I was definitely looking for an explanation like this.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar No problem, this is a frequent source of confusion. Many developers never discover the "threadsafe" APIs and are wondering why asyncio is flaky or slow to respond to `create_task`, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093688/1600898) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912853/1600898). I proposed to fix this by [detecting the problem](https://bugs.python.org/issue33605) and raising an exception, but the proposal was not well accepted for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your code behaves as expected:

> It should be noted that calling this (`run_forever()`) causes our main thread to block
>   indefinitely.

(https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/#the-run-forever-method)

see also [Asyncio How do you use run_forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642267/asyncio-how-do-you-use-run-forever) for solutions (`loop.call_soon_threadsafe()` and `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`).

Comment: The OP is calling `run_forever` in a separate thread, so the sentence doesn't apply. The linked tutorial assumes that you are running the event loop in the main thread, which is often the case, but not always.

Comment: The OP isn't starting the event loop in the thread. He is just executing the `.run_forever()` in the thread.