# Await queue.get is stuck on an empty queue

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I'm having issues with asyncio queues. Execution gets stuck on `await queue.get()` if the queue is empty - even if I publish something into the queue.

I have a loop which reads the event queue, which starts right after the app loads, so the queue is empty on the first await. In a different co-routine I publish a message to this queue, however the execution waits on the await statement. Only a single consumer is reading the queue. I publish the message using `put_nowait()`:

```
    async def _event_loop(self):
    while True:
        try:
            # if self.events.empty():
            #     await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            #     continue
            ev = await self.events.get()
            print(ev)
```

If I uncomment the commented out part, the whole thing starts working.

I noticed a similar issue here:
https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/issues/56

But I had no luck figuring out how to fix this.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your producer isn't letting your consumer run.

Comment: It sounds like, yes indeed. But I believe the issue is somewhere else. The producer here is running in a completely different thread as it is a websocket connection. If the producer would block, why would then the uncommented part of the code fix the issue?

Comment: "The producer here is running in a completely different thread" - asyncio queues are not threadsafe. Most of asyncio is not threadsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the queue from a thread different than the one that runs the event loop. By design, asyncio queues are **not thread-safe** and can only be safely accessed from asyncio coroutines and callbacks.

You can fix the issue by changing your call to `queue.put_nowait(elem)`, to something like `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, elem)`, where `loop` is the event loop object which you must also pass to the thread, probably the same way you pass the queue.

> why would then the uncommented part of the code fix the issue?

Uncommenting effectively removes the need for the coroutine to wake up while waiting on an empty queue. The wakeup didn't work because `put_nowait` assumes it is run from the event loop thread, and therefore doesn't need to emit an additional wakeup signal. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389627/1600898) for details.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help, it works now. I had no idea I cant put item to a queue from a different thread